# Set selected value (value from database) as selected in drop down in ajax response

Tags: javascript, ajax, drop-down-menu, codeigniter-3, selectedvalue

I'm getting a ajax response from my codeigniter controller and I'm setting that values in drop-down list box.

**Here is my code:**

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="cluster_id"><span style="color:red;">*</span>Property Cluster</label>
    <input type="hidden" name="cluster_id_property" id="cluster_id_property" value="<?= $addEditProperty->cluster_id; ?>">
    <select class="form-control" id="cluster_id" name="cluster_id" required="">
        <option value="">Select Cluster</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

**Here is my JS Code:**

```
var cluster_id_property = document.getElementById('cluster_id_property').value;
    var area_id = document.getElementById('area_id').value;
    $.ajax({
        'url'     : '<?= base_url('property/clusterByArea'); ?>',
        'type'    : 'POST',
        'dataType': 'JSON',
        'data'    : {area_id : area_id},
        success   : function(response) {
            $('#cluster_id').find('option').not(':first').remove();
            $.each(response,function(index,data){
                $('#cluster_id').append('<option value="'+data['cluster_id_primary']+'">'+data['cluster_name']+'</option>');
            });
        }
    });
```

My question is how I can set selected value in ajax response ? I want to show selected value in `edit page`.

Any kind of help is welcome, thanks in advance.

Comment: You mean 1) a value the user just now selected? Or 2) a previously-selected value stored in the database? For 1: get the current value of the `<select>` before you make the ajax request, and then in your loop check if the value you're appending matches the existing selection. if it does, add the `selected` attribute to the option. For 2: Send the selected value in the response from the server along with the options, and then proceed in the same way as 1.

Comment: @ADyson I just updated my code, I expecting output for 2nd case.

Comment: ok thanks. So you want to return the existing cluster ID value from the database? In that case you have to modify your server code so that the AJAX call returns an object containing the current selected cluster ID, and also an array containing the options data. But you haven't shown us your server code, so we can't help you with that.

Comment: @ADyson OK, I've a cluster ID stored in database and I'm storing that value in **$addEditProperty->cluster_id** in hidden input field, and getting that value in javascript by **var cluster_id_property**. I'm just need, how can I compare both the values and make HTML element selected = selected in javascript. Is that possible ?

Comment: Ok. So the value is already on the page. I assumed cluster_id_property was something different, since you are sending it to the server (named as area_id at that time), so I thought that was to restrict the list of clusters returned (based on another field), not a cluster ID itself. But you can compare then using `==`, just like anything else. `if (area_id == data['cluster_id_primary'])...etc` and use that to add an extra bit to your string. Or you could use the `(x == y ? "selected" : "")` kind of syntax to easily add it within your existing append command

Comment: @ADyson We can do it in PHP <code><?php if (isset($addEditData->data_id_primary) && ($data->data_id_primary == $addEditData->data_id)) {
 echo "selected='selected'";
} ?></code>. Is this possible in javascript also ?

Comment: yes, you can create any string you like in Javascript. See my edited comment above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily compare the relevant variables and add an extra `selected` attribute to the option string whenever they match. Just add an extra clause into the string you create within the append statement:

```
$('#cluster_id').append('<option value="'+data['cluster_id_primary']+'" '+ (area_id == data['cluster_id_primary'] ? ' selected ' : '') +'>'+data['cluster_name']+'</option>');
```

Comment: Its Working, Thanks. I just misplace the quotes that's I'm not getting the result. BTW Thanks a lot.

Comment: @GaneshAher yes, the syntax can get very confusing when creating elements by appending strings like this. You could consider whether a JS templating engine would make this kind of code easier for you to write and maintain.

Comment: How we can select multiple value in this case? I've array coming from database in php, want to compare and select multiple values

Comment: @GaneshAher if you want to be able to select multiple items in the same select, then set the `multiple` attribute of the dropdown, e.g `<select multiple `...etc. See [Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select) and a [demo](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_select_multiple). If that's not what you're asking, you'll have to clarify it a bit more.

Comment: I want to show multiple values selected in drop-down that comes from database. I got an array stored in database and expecting to show that values as selected in drop-down list.

Comment: In your answer we are showing single selected value that comes from database. What if we got an array from database?

Comment: then for each possible option, you have to loop through all the items in the selected values array, and check if it matches any one of them. The logic is not complex.

Comment: When I'm looping through all items, it gives repeated values. $.each(response,function(index,data) {
                    for (var i = 0; i < cityName.length; i++) {
                        $('#city_name').append('<option value="'+data['city_id_primary']+'" '+(cityName[i] == data['city_id_primary'] ? ' selected ' : '') +'>'+data['city_name']+'</option>');
                    }
                });

Comment: It's trivial to see that this is because because you're running ".append()" once for each city name. That's not what I described. You need to loop through the city names, decide if any of them match data["city_id_primary"], and then use that result to decide whether to write "selected" into the string when you append it. The append should occur after the loop has completed. You'll have to store the result (e.g. a boolean, true for matched, false for not matched) in a variable which you then make us of in the append command. Think through your logic more carefully, it's not complicated.

Comment: You are right, but I'm quite new to JavaScript, I tried it but not success, will you help me in that?

Comment: What is giving you a problem exactly? You don't know how to make a boolean variable? You don't know how to re-use it later? You don't know how to move the append() command outside the loop? I think you _do_ know all those things, if you think about it. It's more that you need to think through the logical process (i.e. algorithm) that you need to use, and then write the code to implement it. The algorithm isn't so complicated, and the code itself isn't so complicated, even if it's all new to you. I think actually you can do it, if you take the time to think about it.

Comment: I tell you what - spend a little while to try it yourself. If you really still can't solve it, ask a new StackOverflow question specifically about this issue. Then we can more clearly see your code and data, and this new problem. Post a link to it here and I'll take a look, but also others can help you. Let me know how you get on, I really believe if you take a bit of time it will become clear to you. I've already given you a good description of what the logic needs to be, so that should start you in the right direction. It's a good challenge but far from impossible.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182311/discussion-between-ganesh-aher-and-adyson).